# How to get order id in Magento/Sales/View/Adminhtml/templates/totals.phtml?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, sales-order

I've tried a lot but can't get current order id from totals.phtml under my adminhtml directory.

Answer (score 5):

```
$orderId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
```

Finally got answer.

Comment: worked for me, try to add explanation as well! +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get current order Id by below code

> echo $block->getOrder()->getId();

Comment: no it's not working

Comment: no function name getOrder() in block file

Comment: I have checked and it's worming.

Comment: send me file path.

Comment: Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Totals.php

Comment: Nee to display in totals.phtml

Comment: My phtml contains   <td>
                     <?php
                    
            $block->getOrder()->getId();


?>
                 </td>

Comment: Give me .phtml file path.

Comment: vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/totals.phtml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72866/discussion-between-suresh-chikani-and-ramesh-kr).

Comment: Write <td> <?php echo $block->getOrder()->getId(); ?> </td> in your phtml file.

Comment: It's working...